# grocery crud upload field "unclickable" in iphone browser

Tags: iphone, ajax, codeigniter, upload, grocery-crud

So I have made a simple site for a friend using codeigniter and grocery crud v1.2, it works well for uploads in all browsers except when I try it on a iphone. For some reason the "choose file" button appears but seems unclickable on the iphone browser only. This means that the upload functionality doesn't work since it doesnt open the "choose file" dialog. Any one notice this before? Like i said it works fine on all desktop browsers and android + opera mini browser.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use that functionality on the iPhone. There's no way to access the phones filesystem from a browser.

You would need to create a native iPhone application to be able to upload files and even then you would be limited to certain filetypes and would not be able to browse the whole file system.

Comment: thank you for giving me one more reason to hate Apple & iphones.